# Inline edit of additional fields in a rallycardboard

Tags: rally, appsdk2

I've got a rallycardboard with cards that are "PortfolioItem/Feature" (using SDK2: rc2).

I've turned on inline editing with the config:

```
editable: true
```

...and this allows me to edit the title inline.  But I'm also displaying the Release field and I'd really like to be able to edit that inline too. Is there a way to enable editing for additional fields like "Release"?

I think inline edit along with the popups is one of the best timesaving features of this cardboard, so I want to expand that as much as possible to additional fields.

Comment: This feature is coming soon in Rally but I'm not sure if it is supported yet in 2.0rc2.  I'll do some digging and hopefully get back to you with some example code to do this in the meantime.

Comment: Thanks-- looking forward to it.